# will alljoyn enabled ios app be approved on app store

Tags: ios, alljoyn

I have been working on the onboarding feature of the alljoyn sdk in an ios app and i was wondering whether my app will be able to get approved on app store or not because in the onboarding process the wifi is automatically changed to my home wifi when the onboarding is complete and I have researched and came to know that this can only be done by a private framework that is not acceptable to app store and i was wondering if alljoyn sdk is using any private framework for this purpose.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: please, could you elaborate on the concept of "private framework"?

Comment: the ones which are not acceptable on the app store because they are accessing private libraries in the ios sdk.